# Doubt in explanation that double dual functor from vector space to itself is naturally isomorphic to identity

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm reading this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1295402/688539), and I am confused what the following equation $\phi^{\vee}(f)  = f \circ \phi$ means. In my understanding, the dual space sends the vector back to field, so how does it make sense to compose a vector with the dual?

Answer (score 1):

In the answer referred to, $\phi$ is a linear map from one vector space $V$ to another $W$.  $\phi^\vee$ is the dual map from $W^\vee$, the space of linear functionals on $W$, to $V^\vee$.  In the definition, $f$ is a member of $W^\vee$, i.e. a linear map from $W$ to the field $k$, and so $f \circ \phi$ is indeed well-defined as a linear map from $V$ to $k$.